# How can I insert a link in Outlook to bookmark it when clicked?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, bookmarks

I'm writing a newsletter in Outlook and I want a clickable 'bookmark it' link to our related staff intranet page.

I can do normal links but want the bookmark action to come up.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it since this is typically done with javascript and Outlook doesn't allow the execution of javascript in email.

You would have to save the content to an attached file which would allow the functionality (although i appreciate it's not very userfriendly).